# Erlang Udp server dropping lots of packets

Tags: sockets, erlang

I've been testing various languages/methods for running a udp server to see which is going to be the most performant. So far I've tested .NET, NodeJs and then Erlang. I'm seeing a problem with this code snip dropping over 50% of the packets I'm sending, whereas node and .net were ~ 4%. The scenario is I'm sending `1000 20 byte messages` as quickly as possible and printing an incrementing number out to the screen. Erlang is only getting ~400 of these. Could you suggest anything I could do to improve that result?

```
-module(udp).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> server(41235) end).

server(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary, {active, false}]),
    io:format("server opened socket:~p~n",[Socket]),
    loop(Socket,0).

loop(Socket,N) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    receive
        {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Bin} ->
            io:format("~p~n",[N]),
            loop(Socket,N+1)
    end.
```

I wouldnt be surprised if I'm totally screwing up this erlang code. I've had a really difficult time wrapping my head around some of the concepts.

My server gratefully borrowed from: http://erlycoder.com/83/erlang-udp-socket-usage-example-with-gen

Here is my client in case you're interested:

```
namespace LocalUdpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        private static long _sentCount = 1;
        private static CustomQueue _queue;
        private static bool _continue = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _queue = new CustomQueue();
            _queue.ItemRemovedEventHandler += QueueOnItemRemovedEventHandler;
            PopulateQueue();
            var con = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient();
            con.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 41235));

            while (_continue)
            {
                byte[] bits = null;
                if (_queue.TryDequeue(out bits))
                {
                    con.SendAsync(bits, bits.Length);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _sentCount);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write(Interlocked.Read(ref _sentCount));
                }

            }

        }

        private static void QueueOnItemRemovedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var queue = sender as CustomQueue;
            if (queue.Count <= 0)
            {
                Task.Run(() => PopulateQueue()).Wait();
            }
        }

        public static void PopulateQueue()
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            RandomNumberGenerator rand2 = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            Parallel.For(0, 1000, p =>
            {
                if (_queue.Count >= 1000) return;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
                rand2.GetBytes(bytes);
                _queue.Enqueue(bytes);
            });



        }

    public class CustomQueue : ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>
    {
        public event EventHandler ItemRemovedEventHandler;

        new public bool TryDequeue(out byte[] item)
        {
            var x = base.TryDequeue(out item);
            if (ItemRemovedEventHandler != null)
            {
                ItemRemovedEventHandler(this,new EventArgs());
            }
            return x;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: i have rum your code, this line `io:format("~p~n",[N]),` seems never exectues. this is no output in erlang shell. Could you tell me what's the reason?

Comment: Did you send it a packet? That line only prints when a packet is recieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike TCP, which guarantees delivery, UDP packets may simply be dropped.  Usually this will be the result of an overflow.  Anywhere you have a producer/consumer relationship you need to be concerned with what happens when the producer outruns the consumer.  With TCP flow control puts back pressure on the sender however with UDP no such back pressure exists.

When you open a UDP socket on the server side it will have a certain amount of memory allocated to receive data from the network.  If your client does not read from the socket as fast as data arrives from the network you will experience a buffer overrun, new UDP packets will overwrite previously received, but not yet read, UDP packets.

You may increase the size of the receive (and transmit) buffer for the socket with the rcvbuf and sndbuf options.  You may have to increase the kernel limits first however (e.g. `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max`).

To see if you are losing UDP packets to kernel buffer overruns inspect the UDP statistics with `netstat -su` (look at 'packet receive errors').

Comment: Thanks, I understand how udp works, I'm looking for help on the erlang code snip. The erlang code is losing 70% of packets while the .net/mono/nodjs/python version is only loosing ~5-10%.

Comment: It's important to understand where they are being lost.  Is the problem that your Erlang server process isn't reading from the socket fast enough?  I have explained how to diagnose that and how to optimize the code for that.

Comment: Ok I can appreciate that. After I reread your answer I see what you are saying now. I have set net.core.rmem_max to 8MB and set the socket recvbuf to 4194304 and now am getting 99.8% success rates. Thank you! One thing I'd be interested in understanding is why the default socket settings would be so low to drop all those packets, whereas python, mono and node were fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe that some packets are lost because at the time of dispatching no one is actively expecting them.
You can decrease number of received packets even further by modifying your Erlang code this way:

```
        io:format("~p~n",[N]),
        receive after 10 -> ok end,
        loop(Socket,N+1)
```

One of the solutions might be using `{active, true}` option, which will ensure that packets instead will be directed to the listening process' mailbox.

As a side note, on my machine the original code could achieve ~99% packet receiving rate, but after adding the delay, the Erlang part could only receive several tens of packets.

Comment: Active true only increased the success marginally ~15%. I should add that my code snip shows loopback as the server, but actually the server is an ec2 ubuntu 14.04 instance and my client is on my home network.

Comment: Were you testing your .NET and Node.js servers on AWS as well?

Comment: Yes using the same environment for node, and a different windows instance for .net. I was going to try and use .NET Core on linux but the System.Sockets namespace isnt finished yet.

Comment: I just recompiled the .net server using mono on the same linux host and had a 96.3% success rate.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 i have rum your code, this line io:format("~p~n",[N]), seems never exectues. this is no output in erlang shell. Could you tell me what's the reason? –